# Programming random distribution with different weights

Tags: c, algorithm, random, pseudocode

The first thing I should say is that probably there is a name for this kind of problem, I simply don't know its name.

The explanation:

There is 8 ball slots and 100 balls to be randomly distributed between the slots. There are 3 different types of slots: red, green and blue. The red slot type must have at least 6 balls total, the green 15 and the blue doesn't matter.

Besides the needed amount for each different colors, there is the possibility of having multiple red, green or blue slots, each one comes with the same rate of the balls that shall go into them. Red is 4%, Green is 15% and Blue is the rest that wasn't picked.

So randomly suggesting a sequence this is a possibility:

```
Slot 1 - Blue with 17 balls
Slot 2 - Green with 8 balls
Slot 3 - Green with 12 balls
Slot 4 - Red with 1 ball
Slot 5 - Blue with 33 balls
Slot 6 - Red with 7 balls
Slot 7 - Blue with 12 balls
Slot 8 - Green with 10 balls
```

Note that the required amounts have been filled, and also there is more than one Red and Green slots, although its only needed one (with at least that total amount of balls inside).

What I need is a pseudo-code or a code in any language showing how to distribute all the 100 balls between different slots and with different weights. I have been programming it but every 3 runs, one fails to distribute every single ball, it misses some.

--EDIT:
A sketch of the code I made in C# (this is only the colored slots generation):

```
    int amountOfRedSlots = 0, amountOfGreenSlots = 0, amountOfBlueSlots = 0;
    int[] slotColors = new int[8]; //1 - red, 2 - green, 3 - blue;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        int num = Random.Range(1, 101);
        if (num <= 4) //Spawn a redSlot
        {
            amountOfRedSlots++;
            slotColors[i] = 1;
        }
        else if (num <= 19) //4 numbers excluded from not being a redSlot and 15 as percentage to be green
        {
            amountOfGreenSlots++;
            slotColors[i] = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            amountOfBlueSlots++;
            slotColors[i] = 3;
        }
    }
    if (amountOfRedSlots < 1)
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(1, 9); //Choose a random slot to be red
        if (slotColors[rand] == 2)
        {
            amountOfGreenSlots--;
        } else amountOfBlueSlots--;
        slotColors[rand] = 1;
        amountOfRedSlots++;
    }
    if (amountOfGreenSlots < 1)
    {
        int rand;
        do
        {
            rand = Random.Range(1, 9);
        } while (slotColors[rand] == 1); //Choose a random slot to be green, but it can't be a former red slot
        amountOfBlueSlots--; //Since there isn't a greenSlot, and we made sure it wasn't red, its certainly a former blue slot
        slotColors[rand] = 2;
        amountOfGreenSlots++;
    }

    //Now its needed to distribute the balls between the slots, giving the required minimum amount to be inside red slots and green slots
    //Also note that there is smaller chance of a ball going inside a red/green slot (4% and 15%)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have currently tried? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I do understand your statement, I said about code needing but what I really need is just some guidance towards the solution, some steps perhaps. The code I've made has over 200 lines, very ununoptimized.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement about multiple red and green slot types. There must be one red slot, so the probability that a slot is red must be at least 12.5%, which is considerably more than 4%.

Comment: I didn't understood where you took 12.5% out of, but the explanation would be: Since there is a need of at least 6 balls within red slots there must be at least one, but not mandatory to be JUST one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work it was a quick code so might have a bug or two. Be careful with what you're stating although low possibility exists with the current layout you might exceed the number of balls to be distributed. Ex: 6 green and 2 red.

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum types{RED=1,BLUE,GREEN};

typedef struct 
{
    int color;
    unsigned int number_balls;
}slot_t;


#define NUM_SLOTS 8
#define GREEN_PROBABILITY 15
#define RED_PROBABILITY 4

#define MINIMUM_RED 6
#define MAX_NUMBER_BALLS 100
int main(void)
{
    slot_t slots[NUM_SLOTS];
    int slots_created,random_number;
    int ball_count=0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(slots_created=0;slots_created<NUM_SLOTS;slots_created++ )
    {
        random_number=rand()%100+1;//random value between 1-100
        if(random_number<=RED_PROBABILITY){
            slots[slots_created].color=RED;
            slots[slots_created].number_balls=MINIMUM_RED;
            ball_count+=MINIMUM_RED;

        }
        else if(random_number<=GREEN_PROBABILITY+RED_PROBABILITY)
        {
            slots[slots_created].color=GREEN;
            slots[slots_created].number_balls=MINIMUM_RED;
            ball_count+=MINIMUM_RED;
        }
        else if(random_number<=GREEN_PROBABILITY)
            ;//blue case
    }   

    while(ball_count<MAX_NUMBER_BALLS)
    {
        slots[rand()%NUM_SLOTS].number_balls+=1; //add one ball
        ++ball_count;
    }


}
```

I'm grabbing a randome value between 1-100 if the number is between 1-4 (4% chance it will be red), if it's between 4 and 19 (note the else if) it will be green, else blue. The same thing occurs with the balls when distributed i grab a random value between 0-7 (8 values) and add a ball to one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but note a few things: You are not forcing the red nor green amount, you are just stating that if it happens to spawn, put that much balls into it, also the amount of balls within a red/green slot is not mandatory to be the 6/15, this amount is required as a total of balls within red/green slots, not in a single one.

One more thing, the "remaining" balls you simply randomize it within the slots, you are not taking into account that the ball has also a rate to go inside a colored slot.